# Vertical align div inside div is not working - CSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Rkh8L/

I am trying to vertically middle div inside div. The class i want to be vertically middles is MonsterImage.

Here the whole code

```
            <div style="float: left; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin:10px;">

                <asp:RadioButton  ID="RdButtonMonsterImages" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

                <div class="permonster" >
                    <div class="MonsterImage"></div>            
                </div>
        </div>



            .permonster
        {
            width: 130px;
            height: 120px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-top: 1px solid #f7fcff;
            background: #ababab;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e3e6e8), to(#ababab));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e6e8, #ababab);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e3e6e8, #ababab);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e3e6e8, #ababab);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e3e6e8, #ababab);
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
            -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding:2px;
        }


            .MonsterImage
            { 
border-width: 0px; border-style: none; 
background-image: url(http://static.monstermmorpg.com/images/csssprites/RegisterCSS.png); 
background-color: transparent; 
margin:auto; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: -0px -120px;  
width: 130px; 
height: 96px;   
            }
```

Comment: added js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Rkh8L/

Comment: solved problem : display:table-cell; to per monster

Comment: The following article explains what you are doing wrong and provides two methods to accomplish what you want. http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't vertical-align that element, just add some margin to the top of your .MonsterImage class, something like `margin-top:13px;` should do it.

Comment: actually MonsterImage margin auto should vertically align it but some how not working.

Comment: Does the width and height of your .monsterimage class change along with the image?

Answer (score 12):

You can center (vertical and horizontal align) a div inside a div as below

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    background-color: #333333;

    position: relative;
    height: 300px; 
    width:300px;
}

#child {
    background-color: #cccccc;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

See [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) article which explains how it works.
Note: Background color is only for illustration purposes only.

See the result below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hate to disappoint you, but this is just not possible with CSS alone.

Here's some things you can do:

- use fixed top and bottom margins on the inner div, and leave the outer div's height at 'auto' (you'll lose control over the outer div's height)
- hard-code everything (you'll lose automatic resizing, obviously)
- use javascript to adjust the sizes on-the-fly after loading the document

Comment: actually it is possible :) solved problem : display:table-cell; to per monster

Comment: well i am also not aiming all browsers. you have to have decent browser to surf on the internet :)

Comment: if only that were true... not having to support IE 6/7 should be the default, but unfortunately, too many users still insist on using them.

Comment: well i cant give support to ie 6 / 7 . those are waste of time :)

Comment: All I'm saying is, sometimes you have to. When you don't, lucky you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3347/discussion-between-tdammers-and-monstermmorpg)

Comment: +1 - Purely because I can't understand how the accepted answer here was the right one, and because I agree with you @tdammers...with variable-height containers you would need something like Javascript to adjust the margins, unless I'm missing something. Why your answer was voted down makes no sense...